# Setting up range slider in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to setup two range sliders in html page and first range slider should not cross the second range slider max value and second slider should not cross the min value of first slider, how do I achieve this.

```html
Min.Length<br><input type="range" id="range_01" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
              <input type="number" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br>
   Max.Length<br><input type="range" name="MaxlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenInput.value=this.value" />
              <input type="number" name="MaxlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two issues. The first, as @JeremyThille pointed out, is you should wrap your form in a `<form>` element. To solve the second issue (preventing sliders from crossing each other), when the range values change, you need to check to see if they are greater/less than the value in the other range slider. If so, you can change the value accordingly.

I added IDs to your second slider and the text inputs next to each slider, just for this demo. You can refer to them in any way you'd like. I also removed the call to `checkLength` in the `onkeyup` attribute of your text inputs.

Note that in the snippet below, you can move the slider handle past the min/max point, but when you let go of the mouse it will snap back to the correct position.

```js
range_01.addEventListener("change", checkMax);
range_01_text.addEventListener("change", checkMax);
range_02.addEventListener("change", checkMin);
range_02_text.addEventListener("change", checkMin);

function checkMax(event) {
  if (parseInt(event.target.value) >= parseInt(range_02.value)) {
    range_01.value = range_02.value;
    range_01_text.value = range_02_text.value;
  }
}

function checkMin(event) {
  if (parseInt(event.target.value) <= parseInt(range_01.value)) {
    range_02.value = range_01.value;
    range_02_text.value = range_01_text.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Min.Length<br><input type="range" id="range_01" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" id="range_01_text" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" /><br> Max.Length
  <br><input type="range" id="range_02" name="MaxlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" id="range_02_text" name="MaxlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenRange.value=this.value" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: But in the text input if I change the value more than the value of the max.length then it is not reverting back to the max value set.

Comment: And one more thing what I have observed is when I move the Max.Length slider below 60 to 45 or 55 it is jumping to 8 and not allowing me to set my desired value(45 or 55).

Comment: @CharanRaj Yes, because you can't have a maxLength less than a minLength.

Comment: @CharanRaj I edited the answer for the text inputs to change too.

Comment: I agree with you but when the Min.length value is set to 8 and Max.length value is set to 60 then I cannot move Max.length value to 45 or 55, If I move it will jump to 8 which is the Min.length value set.
Just run the above snippet and change the value of Max.length to 45 and see, it will jump to 8 and again I cannot move it back to 60. If I move it back to 60 then again it will jump to 8 until I set Max.length value to 80.

Comment: Good catch. I think it was a type cast issue. I added `parseInt` to the if condition in the answer, so I think it should work now.

Comment: Is it possible to get the value for Min.length from the external file (i.e, read value from the external file and set the same for Min.length). So If I change the value in the file, the same value should be displayed in the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The error is : `Cannot read property 'MinlenInput' of null`, meaning `form` is null/undefined.

Just wrap your code in a `<form>` :

```html
<form>
  Min.Length<br><input type="range" id="range_01" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br> Max.Length
  <br><input type="range" name="MaxlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" name="MaxlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br>
</form>
```